# json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&admin) returns empty struct

Tags: json, go, jsondecoder, mux

I know there are a lots of people that has run into the same issue but still here I am. I'm pretty sure my code is correct and still the resulting struct is empty.
Function :

```
func PostAdminHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/json")
    var admin admin.Admin

    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&admin)
    fmt.Println(admin)
    _, err := PostAdmin(admin)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Console print :

```
{     ObjectID("000000000000000000000000")}
```

Structure :

```
package entity

import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

type Admin struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Email     string
    Password  string
    Role      string
    Campus    primitive.ObjectID
}
```

Route :

```
    adminRoute.HandleFunc("/admin", admin.PostAdminHandler).Methods("POST")
```

Json data I'm sending through Insomnia :

```
{
    "FirstName": "Jeanne",
    "LastName": "Darc",
    "Email": "jeanne.darc@rouen.fr",
    "Password": "JeanneDarc2022",
    "Role": "admin",
    "Campus": "60d5a25ff4d722d3b77d1929",
}
```

Error i'm getting from decoder :

```
invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
```

Comment: Check the error from `Decoder.Decode`

Comment: Yeah, sorry i forgot to put it. here it is : ```invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string```

Comment: Remove the last comma after "Campus" in the input

Comment: wow congrats i've been on this for 2 hours... Json doesn't accept commas with no followings ?

Comment: No. The RFC specifies the grammar as: `object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ] end-object`

Comment: Well done, post this as an answer if you want

Comment: as a general rule, it pays to not ignore errors returned from function calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This RFC:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159

specifies the JSON object format as:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value.  **A single comma separates a value from a following**
> **name.**  The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

```
object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
               end-object

member = string name-separator value
```

So, no trailing commas.

Remove the last comma in the input.